# htaccess rules hit 404 when using numbers in url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've following htaccess to generate permalinks for my app:

```
6   #Permalinks
7   RewriteEngine on
8   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
9   RewriteEngine On
10  #catch potential subpages first
11  RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
12  #
13  RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
14  </IfModule>
```

Is correct regexp: `[0-9a-z-]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to match numbers also use these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Does it make difference if letters come firs or numbers?

Comment: No it doesn't make any difference. Just make sure hyphen is first or last to avoid escaping it.